# android google maps api V2: Resize GroundOverlay to fit the screen

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am laying a groundoverlay onto my mapview, I'm able to do this but it just lays it onto the map as a square and that's not really what I'm after. What I would like to do is fit the groundoverlay to cover and fit the whole screen and then disable mapview controls, I've tried resizing the bitmap image before I lay it onto the map but that doesn't seem to change anything.
has anyone done this before or know of a way of doing this?
Code:

```
//-----add ground overlay to map
    public void addGroundOverlay(LatLng point) {

        //add overlay
        Bitmap overlayImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.maptile_normal);
        BitmapDescriptor overlayImageDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(overlayImage);


        GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(overlayImageDescriptor)
            .position(point, 1000, 1000);
        mapView.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlayOptions);
     }
```

thanks

Comment: Just to better understand... do you want to change the background for a specific area or you want to change the background of the map wherever the user is looking at?
GroundOverlays are set for covering a specific geographic area and not "the screen". What do you need to achieve?

Comment: Maybe TileOverlay will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I want to place an image onto the map and then fix the screen to that image so the user cannnot move outside of it. What are the differences between GroundOverlay and TileOverlay?

Comment: GroundOverlay is a unique image that you put somewhere in the world and stays there.
TileOverlay is a set of images that compose the world. Even googlemaps background is a tileoverlay, is has 1 tile at level0, 4 tiles at lv1, 16 at lv2 and so on...
The question i've made is for understand if you need a backround image or a georeferenced image. If your is the first case, you don't need googlemaps! In case of the second, you should zoom and center the image and then "lock" any control in the GoogleMap object